# Run multiple curl calls consecutively with same options

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl call I want to run but once it runs, I would like to run another to a different url but with the same options.

Can I run another call without having to copy and paste the options, I need to run about 5 calls, it seems like there is a way to accomplish this. I cannot run them all at the same time, I need to make sure that I get the result from one, then if certain critera is met, I need to run another one.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Just set each different url with the `CURLOPT_URL` option.

Comment: but wouldnt that run them all without giving me a chance to analyze each call first?

Comment: As long as you didn't close the curl, it would be useable. If you want, you can store the result of each one separately

Comment: Initialize, set all the desired options, execute the first request, do whatever you want with the result.  Update the url, execute, wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: So after result, I can go ahead and make the next two lines before `curl_close($ch);`: `$ch = curl_init($url2); $result2 = curl_exec($ch2);` and it would run with the same options as the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply update the url (using the `CURLOPT_URL` option) before each additional request.   See the comments in the below example.

```
// initialize with the first url you want to use
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// check the result of the first request
if($result == "the content you want")
{
    // if the result dictates that you make another request, update the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);

    // execute the second request
    $result2 = curl_exec($ch);

    // do something with $result2
}

// only close curl after you are done making your requests
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't understood wrongly.

Yes, I always use a way to run 1 cURL action to more than 1 URL.

And you should use:

**EDIT: Method 2 isn't working.**

**Method 1:**

```
<?php
// Arrays
$ch=array();
$url=array();
$result=array();
// ************

$url['1'] = 'http://url1.com';
$url['2'] = 'http://url2.com';

$ch['1'] = curl_init($url['1']);
curl_setopt($ch['1'], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch['1'], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch['1'], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch['1'], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result['1'] = curl_exec($ch['1']);

curl_close($ch['1']);

$ch['2'] = curl_init($url['2']);
curl_setopt($ch['2'], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch['2'], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch['2'], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch['2'], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$result['2'] = curl_exec($ch['2']);
curl_close($ch['2'])
?>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?php
$url = array(
'http://url1.com',
'http://url2.com'
);
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch)
?>
```

In **method 1** we used arrays in `$ch` and `$url` and `$result`

In **method 2** we made array of `$url`

Comment: What is the point in using an array like in the first example? After you have closed the handle you only need to reassign it? `$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $urls[0]); curl_close($ch); $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $urls[1]); curl_close($ch);`. The real solution would be to set the options once, except the url and reuse the open handle for every call.